# how I could hover in the label upload and submit button in order to change the background and text

Tags: html, css

I use this code due to design upload and submit button does not use jquery or Javascript. I need to change upload and submit button background color and text color when hover it.
This is the code : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eafkbmn6/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inputBtnSection {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
}
.disableInputField {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 27px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.fileUpload2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.uploadBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}
.uploadBtn2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.fileUpload2 input.submit {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="formulir">
  <form action="php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="inputBtnSection">

      <input id="uploadFile" class="disableInputField" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />

      <label class="fileUpload">
        <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="fileToUpload" />
        <span class="uploadBtn">Browse File</span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <label class="fileUpload2">
      <input id="uploadtn2" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" class="submit">
      <span class="uploadBtn2">upload</span>
    </label>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: .uploadBtn2:hover{background-color:#000;}

Comment: it cant, check in jsfiddle, I already try it but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg2bs9pq/)

Just added :hover class to the elements.

**CSS:**

```
.fileUpload:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 256, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.25s;  
}

.fileUpload2:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: No problem mate :D happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding this to your css script:

```
.uploadBtn:hover{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: [the color on hover]
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

So I have only added `:hover` after the class name. Then do the same to the submit button.

Comment: I'm already try it, but still cant. why ? because mybe i use the label for button?

Comment: Yeah,, that's right.. Replace .uploadBtn:hover with #uploadBtn:hover .. it is an ID not a class.

Comment: yes that's right , I was wrong I guess do hover in uploadBtn:hover is correct but didnt. ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add an :hover after your class. You only need to add the nessesary changes not everything.

```
.uploadBtn {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
font-size:14px;
padding:0 10px;
height:25px;
line-height:22px;
color:#fff;}

.uploadBtn:hover { 
    background: [your new color];
    color: [your new color];
}
```